# Add a column in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

1. I am Trying to insert one column on an existing CSV file name as test.csv, on column number E.
2. If the column E is already occupied, i Need to shift that column to right and insert new.
3. Column Head should be Day, columns should be filled with current date

Cunnernt Data

Name    Age     location    school 
Adam    12      abc         xyz
eve     14      abc         xyz
Joy     12      abc         xyz

Need Out

```
Name    Age     location    school  Day
Adam    12      abc         xyz     =today()
eve     14      abc         xyz     =today()
Joy     12      abc         xyz     =today()
```

I will have normally 2000 rows

I tried the following code that didn't work for me

```
import csv
Path = 'C:\\Users\\saquib.khan\\Desktop\\Profile_All\\Demo\\New'
infilename = Path + '\\Test.csv'
outfilename = Path + '\\Out1.csv'

 with open(infilename, 'rb') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wb') as fp_out:
 reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
 writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")

 headers = next(reader)  # read title row

 headers[E:E] = ['New Label']

 writer.writerow(headers)

 for row in reader:
 row[E:E] = [0]
 writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does work"? What is happening? Are getting any errors?

Comment: I am getting an error - iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?) , i am using Jupiter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Date

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
dt = now.strftime("%m/%d/20%y")

 F = 'in.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Path1 + F)
df["Day"]=df.shape[0]*[dt]
df.to_csv(Path +"out.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the 2 files in `b` mode (`bytes` instead of `text` mode).
Is there a reason why you are doing it this way?

Have you tried to open them in text mode?

```
with open(infilename, 'r') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'w') as fp_out:
```

Does it work in this case?

Comment: Now i don't have any error but instead of columns i am getting rows

Comment: What do you mean by "getting rows"? Which part of the code? And isn't it the the correct way to get rows when iterating over CSV data?

Comment: I wanted to add new columns on E, with name Day, but now i am getting multiple row

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Could you update your question (or ask a new one) with more information, like examples of the output you get and how that is different from what you expected to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv

Path = 'C:\\Users\\saquib.khan\\Desktop\\Profile_All\\Demo\\New'
infilename = Path + '\\Test.csv'
outfilename = Path + '\\Out1.csv'

with open(infilename, 'rb') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wb') as fp_out:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")

    headers = next(reader)  # read title row

    idx = ord('E') - ord('A')
    headers[idx:idx] = ['New Label']

    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        row[idx:idx] = [0]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Convert the column name to the column index to operate with the Python list.